# Can you restoring the PE header from memory after deleting it?

Tags: c++, c

I was searching through several open source projects and came across one that says it restore PE header after deleting it, but it wasn't included. I was wondering if there was any way to restore the PE header after it had been erased.

Using the following for erasing PE header

```
VOID ErasePEHeaderFromMemory()
{
    _tprintf(_T("[*] Erasing PE header from memory\n"));
    DWORD OldProtect = 0;

    // Get base address of module
    char *pBaseAddr = (char*)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    // Change memory protection
    VirtualProtect(pBaseAddr, 4096, // Assume x86 page size
        PAGE_READWRITE, &OldProtect);

    // Erase the header
    SecureZeroMemory(pBaseAddr, 4096);
}
```

Comment: FYI, the C language does not have `delete`.  Are you mixing languages?  I recommend updating the language tags to the single language you are programming in.

Comment: Please clarify, what is the PE header?  Specifically, what is your definition of PE?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I assume that OP means [Portable Executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).

Comment: Your question does not make much sense to me. Are you talking about attempting to reconstruct PE files which have been partially corrupted?

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel: He is talking about deletion of PE Header from process memory. Its a common practice in anti-RE and malware creation to delete the said header so if you dump process memory you have to rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Usually, if not tampered with, PE Header in memory should be identical to the PE Header of the file from which process was created.

Comment: After deleting it, I'd like to restore it, but I'm not sure if that's possible. I'm currently using https://github.com/LordNoteworthy/al-khaser/blob/master/al-khaser/AntiDump/ErasePEHeaderFromMemory.cpp to remove it from memory.

Comment: Then just read it from the exe file on the disk. But why exactly do you need to restore it? You should do whatever require PE header prior removing it from process memory.

Comment: I need it for my authentication system to work, but I'm now erasing it to prevent anyone from using simple tools like ksdumper to dump it to prevent leaks or cracks.